# Powershell calling function from inside a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hopefully someone can help me here, I'm simply trying to call a function from within a function.

I've created a simple menu that asks for user input and based on the selected menu option it then runs another function that has a select which then calls other functions depending on the original menucode selected.

In short I would to pass the custom objects from each function to the next without returning to the main script menu loop. I've googled and can't seem to find a clear answer and/or code example explaining how to do this.

After Jaitsu comment below, I've removed a good portion of my code and have pasted the script so that you can clearly see my issue first hand.

Jaitus mentioned use a echo which really is just an alias for write-output. I would like use output properties in other functions without returning to the main script loop. Is this even possible to do or do I need to leave the function to create a variable that then is used to pass to the next function script block ?

Example Function A returns an object but the script never leaves a function before calling the next which looks for a return from the first script block.

Code and comments attached to further illustrate my dilemma, not even sure this is possible to do and if not, then any additional suggestions for how to to do my menu loop would be greatly appreciated.

* fixing code, and will post back to share when completed ***
      Thanks everyone for your input...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output several variables from function (if this is what you want), you can use several approaches:

**Scopes**

You can assign variables in outer scope directly from function:

```
$modifiedArg1 = $null
$modifiedArg2 = $null

Function Modify-OuterScope {
    Param ($Arg)
    $Script:modifiedArg1 = "Modified '$arg' first outer variable"
    $Script:modifiedArg2 = "Modified '$arg' second outer variable"        
}

Modify-OuterScope -Arg 'test'
Write-Host $modifiedArg1  # Modified 'test' first outer variable
Write-Host $modifiedArg2  # Modified 'test' second outer variable
```

You can find more about scopes in [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) article or in [my post](http://personal-code.blogspot.com/2012/08/one-character-drama.html).

**Pipeline**

If you returning more than one object, like:

```
Function Foo {
    "string one"
    "string two"
}
```

they will be returned as array, and you can pipe it in ordinary way:

```
Function Foo {
    "string one"
    "string two"
}

Foo | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Returned item: '$_'" }
```

Please, be aware of potential [problems](http://personal-code.blogspot.com/2012/08/item-or-array.html).

**Complex result**

Also you can construct some complex object, as SpellingD write, and return it. But I would prefer Hashtable instead of PSObject, if there is no need of methods linked with that object:

```
# create complex result
Function Create-NewAdmin {
    @{ 
        Name = "Root";
        Password = "Admin123"
    }
}

# Use complex result    
Function Write-User {
    Param($user)

    Write-Host $user.Name
    Write-Host $user.Password    
}

$admin = Create-NewAdmin

Write-User $admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little difficult for me to interpret, but this sounds like your main issue

```
 If I create $emailname = $username.emailname doesn't seem to return anything from the previous function which I need to pass to the next function main_input
```

In Powershell, variables created in functions stay in those functions, after it's done, the variables go with them. So if you are creating an object that you want to pass, you need to have the function output the object and use a call to that function as an assignment to a variable. It seems like you are making the object as the $user variable within your script. So if you would like to pass this object on, you would do something similar to the following

```
function example{
    <string initializations>
    $user = new-object PSObject
    <assign properties to $user>
    echo $user
}

$myObject = example
SomeOtherFunction $myObject
```

This sets $myObject to the object that you created as $user (because echoing $user at the end of that function serves as a "return" value, so to speak), so you can then pass $myObject to other functions, and calling $myObject.property would be equal to the value that was set when you were creating the object.

Note:

```
# $user = name_split
```

1. This will just erase all the work you did previously in creating $user as a new object
2. $username you have defined as a string, so it won't have the custom property "emailname" because that was created in $user. So, in that function, $user.emailname would return what you added to the $user object as property "emailname"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, in a nutshell I want to use the function name properties to pass parameters to other functions. I tried everything to output it, just not echo. So there's no way to pass a custom-object property to another fuction as its input.

Comment: Yeah, in a nutshell I want to use the function name properties to pass parameters to other functions. I tried everything to output it, just not echo. So there's no way to pass a custom-object property to another function as its input.  such as function split_name.displayname and/or any other property

Comment: Disregard my last comment, you've already answered it. "pass $myObject to other functions, and calling $myObject.property would be equal to the value that was set when you were creating the object"

Comment: Yep, so when $myObject is set to an object you can then pass it's property as an argument in a fashion of **<function> $myObject.emailname** and it will pass just the value of $myObject.emailname

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback SpellingD, Unfortunately I'm a vbscript convert and am working on changing my scripts from vb to powershell. Can you clarify a little more as to the actual syntax that would be used while inside a function and/or calling that object from another function?  I'm not sure what you mean by <function> Do you mean ({main_input}$username.emailname) Would you mind writing a quick example using the names of my functions such as calling the main_input from names etc so that I can see the syntax used.

Comment: I've actually never worked with VBScript so I'm a little unfamiliar with your syntax! PowerShell is driven like a command line, so it's syntax goes in the form of **function arg1 arg2** etc. The main point being that whitespaces separate function calls and other arguments.
For your example, you could do something like this:
`main_input $menucode $user`
$user would have to be defined as an object, and in your script, $username you have created as a string, so until you reassign it to an object, $username will not have any custom properties, only default ones like .length

Comment: That's perfect, Ok I'll remove the assignment of the [string] to the $username variable. I was under the impression I first needed to define it as a string for the input and then also as a string in the custom object.  I'll make the appropriate changes, thanks for you help, this has been driving me nuts..

Comment: Just for more clarification, because I'm not sure if what you are supposing to do is correct. First off, Powershell will take text strings and auto-assign them to strings, so in fact, [string] is almost never needed anywhere. What I meant is, that nowhere in your script, is $username ever made into a custom object. Only $user I see is a custom object. Until you define $username as an object that you have manually added the property "emailname" to, it will ALWAYS return null for $username.emailname.

Comment: actually I removed the $username variable when cleaning up the code to post it online.  I understand what you mean, and will make the adjustments to the other functions using it.  The original code looks more like this, name_split($username)
   $username = name_split

Comment: worked perfectly                                                               $user = name_split $username
    $logonname = $user.logonname
 
    DEBUG: name_split: Logon Name   -- tuser
    DEBUG: name_split: Email Name   -- Test.User@mytest.com
    DEBUG: name_split: Domain Name  -- tuser@mytest2.com
    DEBUG: calling main_input: menucode -- ucr
    DEBUG: calling main_input: username.logonname -- tuser

Comment: You rock thanks for the assistance, In the main script I'll change $user to $username so it works with my original code..   Thanks man..